# IPython notebook export external svg to pdf

Tags: pdf, svg, jupyter-notebook

In a markdown cell in an ipython3 notebook (4.0.0) I include an svg that is located together with the notebook file:

```
<img src="NewTux.svg"/>
```

In the normal notebook view it is displayed as expected. 
However, when I try to export to pdf the image does not show up.

What puzzles me is that a matplotlib plot (with `%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'`) perfectly shows both on screen AND in the exported PDF.

How can I get a PDF including also the svgs which are not plotted but just included as a figure in markdown? 
(A workaround is to print to pdf in browser, but then I miss LaTeX-formatting and formula and color in the syntax-highlighting of the code sections).

Minimum working example for the ipython file is:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
    "collapsed": false
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": [
    "%matplotlib inline\n",
    "%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'\n",
    "import numpy as np\n",
    "import matplotlib.pyplot as pp\n",
    "\n",
    "x = np.arange(0,10,0.05)\n",
    "y = np.sin(x)\n",
    "\n",
    "pp.plot(x,y)\n",
    "pp.show()"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "<img src=\"NewTux.svg\">"
   ]
  },
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": null,
   "metadata": {
    "collapsed": true
   },
   "outputs": [],
   "source": []
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 3",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python3"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 3
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython3",
   "version": "3.4.3"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

Where I downloaded: [NewTux.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:NewTux.svg) from the Wikimedia commons.

Comment: Can you post the notebook file?

Comment: @nluigi Yes, of course. Please see my updated question.

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating the issue. I tried out your example (with Python 2.7 and IPython 4 / Jupyter), and the image didn't show up even in the notebook form.

Comment: Ah, my replication problem was a browser issue. The image doesn't show in the notebook on Internet Explorer, but it does for Firefox.

Comment: @ScottH So it's reproducable, that's already good to know, thanks for testing. :)